# Accessing object in returned promise using fetch w/ react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I have this function:

```
  getUserData() {
    fetch(this.props.apiUrl + this.state.username + '?client_Id=' + this.props.clientId + '&client_secret=' + this.props.clientSecret)
      .then(function(response) {
        var data = response.json();
        this.setState({
          userData: data
        });
        console.log(this.state.userData);
      }.bind(this))
      .catch(function(error) {
        this.setState({
          username: null
        });
        console.log(error)
      }.bind(this)) 
  }
```

Which returns this in the console:

Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}

**proto**
  [[PromiseStatus]] : "resolved"

```
[[PromiseValue]] : Object
avatar_url : "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/"
login      : "hello world"
.
.
.
```

I need to access the name/value pairs in the object but I can't get to them. I'm assuming I need to take one extra step after I convert the response to json but can't figure it out. If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is also a promise, so you need `return response.json()` and handle it in the next `.then()`

Comment: Thank you zerkms, this worked!

Comment: You know what to do then ;-)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`response.json()` returns a promise, so you also need to handle it appropriately, eg:

```
.then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
})
.then(function(parsedData) {
    // data here
})
```

Comment: is it possible to store it in a var rather then do return? also if I have the parentheses I get `response.json is not a function`.

Comment: @tatsu please ask another question with more details

Comment: same response.json is not a function

Comment: @ΔημήτρηςΦιλίππου same thing: please ask another question with more details

Answer (score 8):

Here's an even shorter way to handle json objects

```
fetch(endpoint, request)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => {
  //handle json response
}
```

Comment: Best solution for React fetch Response

Answer (score 0):

just use await:
`response = await response.json();`
and you will have the object in the response, sure you have to set the function to async first like
`async getUserData(){....}` and use await before the fetch too.